# Html encode language signs with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encoding

I need to encode different languages signs with javascript (mostly german signs). For example I need to have this:

```
Bemerkung für alles
```

Encoded to this:

```
Bemerkung f&uuml;r alles
```

I search for that and I know that this can do the trick:

```
$('<div/>').text('<div>Bemerkung für alles</div>').html();
```

But unfortunately it only encodes some other signs for example: '<', '>', '&' and so on.
Is there any option to encode such signs with javascript/jQuery without creating an array of signs to change and do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may encode them to unicode sequence:

```
var s = "Bemerkung für alles";
//                   vvvvvv--here are ignored chars :a-zA-Z0-9-?!{space}
var r = s.replace(/[^\w -?!]/g, function(c) {
    return '&#'+c.charCodeAt(0)+';';
});
// r = "Bemerkung f&#252;r alles"
$('<a>').html(r).text() == s //true
```

Comment: This line: r = s.replace(/[^\w -?!]/g,c=>'&#'+c.charCodeAt(0)+';'); is causing a syntax error.

Comment: @Otishone Just tested, it's working. try `"Bemerkung für alles".replace(/[^\w -?!]/g,c=>'&#'+c.charCodeAt(0)+';');`

Answer (score 0):

Not that i know of, he.js should do the trick though if you dont mind pulling in another lib. 
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he

Comment: Yes this is and option, I saw that earlier, just I'm thinking if there is an option not to use it. But I suppose that I will end up on that if anything else will come up.

Answer (score 0):

you can use encodeURI("Bemerkung für alles")

Comment: This will return 'Bemerkung%20f%C3%BCr%20alles' and will not encode it as I prefer to.

Answer (score 0):

since this came up when I wanted to encode especially `<>&` signs (and did not want to install `he.js`) I improved @Dimava's answer for this case:

one liner:

```
s.replace(  /[^\w -?!]|[<>&]/g,  c => '&#'+c.charCodeAt(0)+';'  )
```

as function:

```
/** e.g. "kleine kacke < Große Kacke && foo" => "kleine kacke &#60; Gro&#223;e Kacke &#38;&#38; foo" */
encHtml( s ) { return  s.replace(  /[^\w -?!]|[<>&]/g,  c => '&#'+c.charCodeAt(0)+';'  )}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Otishone you can do something like

var temp = encodeURI("Bemerkung für alles");
temp.replace(/%20/g, " ");